# DotNetBrowser Video Capture isn't working

Tags: html, dotnetbrowser

I am newly working with DotNetBrowser. wanted to record video using the webcam. is there any way to do that using Dotnetbrwser?

```
 IMediaDevices mediaDevices = engine.MediaDevices;
 IEnumerable<MediaDevice> videoDevices = mediaDevices.VideoCaptureDevices;
 IEnumerable<MediaDevice> audioDevices = mediaDevices.AudioCaptureDevices;
 browser = engine.CreateBrowser ();
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, DotNetBrowser does not perform video capturing directly. However, you can consider creating a web page that uses WebRTC MediaStream Recording API and displaying it in DotNetBrowser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API

Here is an example of the web page that captures the video from the web camera:

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/

https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/record

In case of any further questions, feel free to contact us at customer-care@teamdev.com.